# Different Behavior while calling Attributes from Class and Instance Variables

Tags: python

I defined such simple class as below:

```
>>> class myclass(object):
    name = "google"
```

And I am creating an instance to call name attribute

```
>>> a = myclass()
>>> a.name
'google'
```

and also calling it directly from the class itself.

```
>>> myclass.name
'google'
```

So far (as I am having background with C# and Java) I will call `myclass.name` static invocation and calling static members from instances are fine.

**But** what I am observing is till I set `a.name` with another value, changing `myclass.name` is also affecting `a.name`. Once I set `a.name`, changing `myclass.name` doesn't affect the `a.name` any more and they begin to have different values.

You can see the whole experiment below:

```
>>> class myclass(object):
    name = "google"


>>> myclass.name
'google'
>>> a = myclass()
>>> a.name
'google'
>>> myclass.name = "yahoo"
>>> a.name
'yahoo'
>>> myclass.name = "hello world"
>>> a.name
'hello world'
>>> myclass.name
'hello world'
>>> myclass.name = "another trick"
>>> myclass.name
'another trick'
>>> a.name
'another trick'
>>> a.name = "I changed the value of a"
>>> a.name
'I changed the value of a'
>>> myclass.name
'another trick'
>>> myclass.name = "changed again"
>>> a.name
'I changed the value of a'
```

I would like someone to explain the reason behind this behavior.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I took a look at [Python Data Model](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html) documentation. If you skip ahead to "Class instances" section, you will see the crucial explanation:

> Attribute assignments and deletions update the instance’s dictionary,
>   never a class’s dictionary.

So in your example, when you do `a.name = ...`, you introduce a new key `name` into a's `__dict__`. After that when you access `name` attribute, the standard attribute lookup mechanism looks into a's `__dict__` first.